# adding a column to a specific row in dataset

Tags: c#, dataset

I have a dataset.
I want to iterate it and add a column (currently not in my dataset) with different value to every row. More specificly, i want it to be at 0 index.
I want to check the value in "fullname" column, and then add a new column with Id.
What do i need to write?

I iterate like this:

```
        foreach (DataRow theRow in mesakem.Tables["fullname"].Rows)
          foreach(oved o in ovdimlist)
              if(o.name==theRow.ToString())
                 add column(o.id)......
```

Ty very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to insert a new column at index 0 and then add *id* values to cell for each row where current *name* cell value matches your object name. If I'm right, it should look like this:

```
DataColumn col = mesakem.Tables["fullname"].Columns.Add("Id");
col.SetOrdinal(0);
foreach (DataRow row in mesakem.Tables["fullname"].Rows)
{
    foreach (oved o in ovdimlist)
    {
        if (o.name == row["Name"].ToString())
            row["Id"] = o.id;
    }
}
```

Comment: this row: mesakem.Tables["fullname"].Columns.Add("Id").SetOrdinal(0);
throwing System.NullReferenceException {Object reference not set to an instance of an object.}